# Why the following equality is true?

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

> Let $A=(A_1,...,A_n) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^n$, why we have
>   $$w_e(A):=\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|\langle A_ix\;,\;x\rangle|^2\bigg)^{1/2}= \displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\sup_{(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)\in B_n}\bigg|\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\langle A_ix\;,\;x\rangle\bigg|\;?$$
>   with $B_n$ is the open unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

And you for you help.

Comment: Do you use the Euclidean norm in $B_n$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami yes I use the Euclidean norm in $B_n$.

Comment: So, you are aware of the reverse inequality, and you are trying to prove equality?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the operators really. You always have $\sup_\lambda |\sum \lambda_i y_i|=\sqrt{\sum |y_i|^2} =:\alpha$. To see this, use Cauchy Schwarz (for one direction), and choose $\lambda_i = \overline{y_i} /\alpha$ (for the other direction).

Comment: @MartinArgerami You are right I see the paper and it is an equality not inequality. I hope that you help me by an answer in order to understand it and thank you

Comment: You already got your answer  (in the comments, unfortunately) by PhoemueX above.

Comment: @PhoemueX  I hope that you write your comment as an answer

Comment: You can write your equality as $$\sup\{|\langle \lambda,\nu\rangle|:\ \|\lambda\|=1\}.$$ So you can see it as HB in the sense that the equality can be seen as $$\|\nu\|=\sup\{|\lambda(\nu)|:\ \lambda\in H^*\}.$$ But you can prove the equality with Cauchy-Schwarz, as PhoemueX said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, for arbitrary complex numbers $\nu_1,\dots,\nu_n$, you have
$$
\sup_{(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n) \in B_n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j \nu_j\right|
= \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n |\nu_j|^2} =:\alpha.
$$
To see this, use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to get "$\leq$". For the reverse inequality, choose $\lambda_j = \overline{\nu_j}/(\alpha+\epsilon)$ for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$

In more fancy language, the above is the characterization of the $\ell^2$ norm by duality.

If you apply this with $\nu_j = \langle A_j x,x \rangle$, you get your claim. Thus, the claim is not really related to the operators, it is just a statement about the $\ell^2$ norm.